# Engineering Format of y-axis values in AChartEngine for Android

Tags: android, achartengine, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I am working on a project where I need plotting data. I use Android Studio 5.2.0 and AChartEngine 1.2.0 on a Windows 7 64 bits PC.
I am interested in engineering formatting of y-labels, e.g. 2.3E6..
I have studied what I could without any success.
I wish 1, 3, 0, 1 and 1 as min No. of integer digits, max No. of integer digits, min No. of fraction digits, max No. of fraction digits and no. of digits in the exponent part, respectively. In addition the exponent must be a muliple of 3.

Here is my LineGraph class:

```
public class LineGraph
{
    public Intent getIntent(Context context)
    {
        int size = ( int ) Math.pow(2, 10);
        double start = 0;
        double end = 2 * Math.PI;
        double inc = (end - start) / (size - 1);
        double[] x = new double[size];
        double[] y = new double[size];

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Sin * Cos");
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            x[i] = start + i * inc;
            y[i] = 10000 * Math.sin(x[i]) * Math.cos(x[i]);
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series);
        XYSeriesRenderer ren = new XYSeriesRenderer();

        // XYSeriesRenderer properties
        ren.setColor(Color.RED);
        ren.setFillPoints(true);
        ren.setDisplayBoundingPoints(false);
        ren.setFillPoints(true);
        ren.setLineWidth(2f);

        // XYMultipleSeriesRenderer properties
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRen = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRen.setAntialiasing(true);
        mRen.setMargins(new int[] { 10, 80, 10, 10 });
        mRen.setShowGrid(true);
        mRen.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRen.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        mRen.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRen.setLabelsTextSize(20f);
        mRen.setYLabelsVerticalPadding(-5f);
        mRen.setYLabelsPadding(40);
        mRen.setShowLegend(false);
        mRen.setXLabels(5);
        mRen.setYLabels(10);

        // Number format
        DecimalFormat noFormat = new DecimalFormat("##0.##E0");
        noFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
        noFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);
        noFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        noFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        mRen.setYLabelFormat(noFormat, 0);
        mRen.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        // Construct and return the intent.
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRen, "Line Graph");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if ( id == R.id.action_settings )
        { return true; }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void lineGraphHandler(View view)
    {
        LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph();
        Intent lineIntent = lineGraph.getIntent(this);
        startActivity(lineIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="ramin.graphtutorial.graph.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_linegraph"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="lineGraphHandler"
        android:text="@string/button_line_graph_text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, this is my manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="ramin.graphtutorial.graph"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="ramin.graphtutorial.graph.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

It works fine when I apply the format method of noFormat to a single double value, but not for fomatting y-labels. For the latter I do the following;

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRen = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
XYSeriesRenderer ren = new XYSeriesRenderer ();
mRen.addSeriesRenderer(ren);
int noOfYLabels = 5;
mRen.setYLabels( noOfYLabels );
mRen.setYLabelFormat( noFormat, 0 );
```

But then I only get three zeros, i.e., 000 for all values along y-axis which is larger than 1000.
I have also tried to manually setting y-value text labels, by the following code snippet:

```
Double[] ylabels = mRen.getYTextLabelLocations(0);
mRen.setYLabels( 0 );
for ( int i = 0; i < noOfYLabels; i++ )
{ mRen.addYTextLabel( ylabels[ i ], noFormat.format( ylabels[ i ] ) ); }
```

But then I get index out of bound in the array yLabels.
Could somebody please help me on this issue?
PS: I asked this question previously, but didn't get any answers. Maybe the question was not clear enough.
Thank you in advance.
Ramin.

Comment: what format u want to display?

Comment: Thank you @keshav for your respond. I want engineering number format of y-labels, e.g. the numbers 600 000 000 and 1 800 must be shown as 600E6 and 1.8E3. In addition y-labels must be authomatically updated on zomming. Thanks again.

Comment: ur noFormat is fine . Problem is somewhere else, can u show more code of the graph ?

Comment: To @keshav. I have included most of my code in the edited version above as you asked for it.

Comment: I have tried ur code everything is fine .

Comment: To @keshav: What do you mean by Ok? Do you get engineering notaion on y-axis, e.g. 2E3, 4E3 etc ou do you also get 000 as I? Any suggestion, comments or guesses where the issue might be in this case?

Comment: May be u didn't place it correctly and its not in visible area.

Comment: To @keshav: I don't know what you mean by placing things correctly, but just in case I have also included activity_main.xml and manifest.xml files above. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I commented for other question here wrongly , see my answer it is what I tried.

Comment: Hi Do you solve Y label formatting?. I have same issue .

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    private LinearLayout chartLayout;
    private GraphicalView mChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showlineGraph( );
    }

    public void showlineGraph()
    {
        chartLayout=    (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphHolder);
//      LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph();

        int size = (int) Math.pow(2, 10);
        double start = 0;
        double end = 2 * Math.PI;
        double inc = (end - start) / (size - 1);
        double[] x = new double[size];
        double[] y = new double[size];

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Sin * Cos");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            x[i] = start + i * inc;
            y[i] = 1000 * Math.sin(x[i]) * Math.cos(x[i]);
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series);
        XYSeriesRenderer ren = new XYSeriesRenderer();

        // XYSeriesRenderer properties
        ren.setColor(Color.RED);
        ren.setFillPoints(true);
        ren.setDisplayBoundingPoints(false);
        ren.setFillPoints(true);
        ren.setLineWidth(2f);

        // XYMultipleSeriesRenderer properties
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRen = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRen.setAntialiasing(true);
        mRen.setMargins(new int[] { 10, 80, 10, 10 });
        mRen.setShowGrid(true);
        mRen.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRen.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        mRen.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRen.setLabelsTextSize(20f);
        mRen.setYLabelsVerticalPadding(-5f);
        mRen.setYLabelsPadding(40);
        mRen.setShowLegend(false);
        mRen.setXLabels(5);
        mRen.setYLabels(10);

        // Number format
        DecimalFormat noFormat = new DecimalFormat("##0.##E0");
        noFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
        noFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);
        noFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        noFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        mRen.setYLabelFormat(noFormat, 0);
        mRen.addSeriesRenderer(ren);

        // Construct and return the intent.
        view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, mRen);
        chartLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: To @keshav. Thanks a lot. It worked as a charm. As far as I could see the difference between approaches was that I started a new Activity, while you used the same Activity to plot the graph. So why wouldn't it go with a New Activity?